# form.save() populates lates row instead of creating a new - Django

Tags: django, post, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a Klient with a post statement, but instead of creating a new row in the DB it replaces the latest one.

The point of my view is to create two models from one POST. Eventually the code should check if a version of Klient exist, if so only create the Booking.

Model:

```
class Klient(models.Model):
  namn = models.CharField(max_length=124)
  adress = models.CharField(max_length=124)
  kontakt = models.CharField(max_length=124)

class KlientForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Klient
    fields = ['namn', 'adress', 'kontakt']

class Bokning(models.Model):
    klient = models.ForeignKey('Klient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    referens = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    pumpStr = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    slangStr = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    pump = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    maskinist = models.CharField(max_length=124, blank=True)
    betongLev = models.CharField(max_length=124, blank=True)
    betongKvalite = models.CharField(max_length=124, blank=True)
    bestalld = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    pumpMng = models.IntegerField()
    datum = models.DateField()
    littNr = models.IntegerField()
    arbNr = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    resTid = models.IntegerField()
    grundavgift = models.IntegerField()
    pumpStart = models.DateTimeField()
    pumpSlut = models.DateTimeField()
    ovrigInfo = models.CharField(max_length=124, blank=True

class BokningForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bokning
        fields = [
            'referens',
            'pumpStr',
            'slangStr',
            'pump',
            'maskinist',
            'betongLev',
            'betongKvalite',
            'bestalld',
            'pumpMng',
            'datum',
            'littNr',
            'arbNr',
            'resTid',
            'grundavgift',
            'pumpStart',
            'pumpSlut',
            'ovrigInfo']
```

View:

```
def bokning(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    klientForm = KlientForm(json.loads(request.body.decode()))
    bokningForm = BokningForm(json.loads(request.body.decode()))
    if klientForm.is_valid() and bokningForm.is_valid():
        klient = klientForm.save()
        bokning = bokningForm.save(commit=False)
        bokning.klient = klient
        bokning.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=201)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
else:
    return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])
```

Trying to create several Boking or Klient in a row results in an updated version of the latest one created. It does not produce any errors, except from the test assertions.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this only happen in tests, or can you reproduce it outside?

Comment: I'm not 100% on what you are doing here, but why are you assigning klientForm.save() to klient, instead of just using klientForm?

Comment: klientForm will still be pointing to the saved KlientForm once you save it, so it isn't necessary to assign it elsewhere.  I'm just thinking that bit of redundancy might be causing an issue.

Comment: @DanielRoseman have not tried this outside of my tests.

Comment: @TimmSimpkins Using save() on a modelForm returns the model, so it does not work if i dont assign it to a new var.

Comment: I would not use "bokning" as a function name and as you form name.

Comment: @Ryan How come? With the risk of answering my own question, I was planning to write most code in Swedish, but that became quite hard as my app evolved and I am now stuck with a mix of both languages.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was located in my tests, not my view. I hade two test that sent POST request, like

```
def test_postBokning(self):
     response = self.client.post('/api/bokning/', json.dumps('a bunch of json'}), content_type='application/json')
     #assertions
def test_postBokningCopy(self):
     response = self.client.post('/api/bokning/', json.dumps('a bunch of json'}), content_type='application/json')
     #assertions
```

I moved the last POST into the first test, which removed my issue.